# Why is ls -R called "recursive" listing?

Tags: command-line, ls

I understand that `ls -R` displays a listing of directories.
But why is it recursive? How is recursion used in the process?

Comment: The intuition is that directories and their subdirectories can be easily modeled using a tree. Algorithms to walk trees are typically recursive.

Comment: @Kevin I don't think there's any need to invoke the concept of trees to answer each question - the answer is simply that when `ls` encounters a directory it recursively lists that directory.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

First off, let's define an arbitrary folder structure:

```
.
├── a1 [D]
│   ├── b1 [D]
│   │   ├── c1
│   │   ├── c2 [D]
│   │   │   ├── d1
│   │   │   ├── d2
│   │   │   └── d3
│   │   ├── c3
│   │   ├── c4
│   │   └── c5
│   └── b2 [D]
│       ├── c6
│       └── c7
├── a2 [D]
│   ├── b3 [D]
│   │   ├── c8
│   │   └── c9
│   └── b4 [D]
│       ├── c10 
│       └── c11
├── a3 [D]
│   ├── b5
│   ├── b6
│   └── b7
└── a4 [D]
```

When we do `ls`, we get the output of the base folder only:

```
a1 a2 a3 a4
```

However, when we call `ls -R`, we get something different:

```
.:
a1  a2  a3  a4

./a1:
b1  b2

./a1/b1:
c1  c2  c3  c4  c5

./a1/b1/c2:
d1  d2  d3

./a1/b2:
c6  c7

./a2:
b3  b4

./a2/b3:
c8  c9

./a2/b4:
c10  c11

./a3:
b5  b6  b7

./a4:
```

As you can see, it's running `ls` on the base folder, and then all the child folders. And all the grandchild folders, ad infinitum. Effectively, the command is going through each folder *recursively* until it hits the end of the directory tree. At that point, it comes back up a branch in the tree and does the same thing for any sub-folders, if any.

Or, in pseudo-code:

```
recursivelyList(directory) {
    files[] = listDirectory(directory)              // Get all files in the directory
    print(directory.name + ":\n" + files.join(" ")) // Print the "ls" output
    for (file : files) {                            // Go through all the files in the directory
        if (file.isDirectory()) {                   // Check if the current file being looked at is a directory
            recursivelyList(directory)              // If so, recursively list that directory
        }
    }
}
```

And because I can, a [reference Java implementation](https://gist.github.com/KazWolfe/f0ae26a7f0c5a5827d87b696834ed7b5) of the same.

Answer (score 23):

There are, in effect, two closely coupled questions you may be asking.

- Why is the process of walking to each entry in a filesystem hierarchy an inherently recursive process? This is addressed by the other answers, such as [Zanna's](https://askubuntu.com/a/875375/22949) and [Kaz Wolfe's](https://askubuntu.com/a/875376/22949).
- How is the *technique* of recursion used in the implementation of `ls`? From your phrasing ("How is recursion used in the process?"), I think this is part of what you want to know.  This answer addresses that question.

#### Why it makes sense for `ls` to be implemented with a recursive technique:

[FOLDOC](http://foldoc.org/) defines [*recursion*](http://foldoc.org/recursion) as:

> When a [function](http://foldoc.org/function) (or [procedure](http://foldoc.org/procedure)) calls itself. Such a function
>   is called "recursive". If the call is via one or more other functions
>   then this group of functions are called "mutually recursive".

The natural way to implement `ls` is to write a function that constructs a list of filesystem entries to be displayed, and other code to process path and option arguments and to display the entries as desired. That function is highly likely to be implemented recursively.

During option processing, `ls` will determine if it has been asked to operate recursively (by being invoked with the `-R` flag). If so, the function that builds a list of entries to be displayed will call itself once for each directory it lists, except `.` and `..`. There may be separate recursive and nonrecursive versions of this function, or the function may check each time if it is supposed to be operating recursively.

Ubuntu's `/bin/ls`, the executable that runs when you run `ls`, is provided by [GNU Coreutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/coreutils.html), and it has *many* features. As a result, [its code](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/ls.c) is somewhat longer and more complicated than you might expect. **But Ubuntu also contains a simpler version of `ls`, provided by [BusyBox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BusyBox).** You can run this by typing `busybox ls`.

#### How `busybox ls` uses recursion:

`ls` in BusyBox is implemented in [`coreutils/ls.c`](https://bazaar.launchpad.net/~vcs-imports/busybox/trunk/view/head:/coreutils/ls.c). It contains a `scan_and_display_dirs_recur()` function that is invoked to print a directory tree recursively:

```c
static void scan_and_display_dirs_recur(struct dnode **dn, int first)
{
    unsigned nfiles;
    struct dnode **subdnp;

    for (; *dn; dn++) {
        if (G.all_fmt & (DISP_DIRNAME | DISP_RECURSIVE)) {
            if (!first)
                bb_putchar('\n');
            first = 0;
            printf("%s:\n", (*dn)->fullname);
        }
        subdnp = scan_one_dir((*dn)->fullname, &nfiles);
#if ENABLE_DESKTOP
        if ((G.all_fmt & STYLE_MASK) == STYLE_LONG || (G.all_fmt & LIST_BLOCKS))
            printf("total %"OFF_FMT"u\n", calculate_blocks(subdnp));
#endif
        if (nfiles > 0) {
            /* list all files at this level */
            sort_and_display_files(subdnp, nfiles);

            if (ENABLE_FEATURE_LS_RECURSIVE
             && (G.all_fmt & DISP_RECURSIVE)
            ) {
                struct dnode **dnd;
                unsigned dndirs;
                /* recursive - list the sub-dirs */
                dnd = splitdnarray(subdnp, SPLIT_SUBDIR);
                dndirs = count_dirs(subdnp, SPLIT_SUBDIR);
                if (dndirs > 0) {
                    dnsort(dnd, dndirs);
                    scan_and_display_dirs_recur(dnd, 0);
                    /* free the array of dnode pointers to the dirs */
                    free(dnd);
                }
            }
            /* free the dnodes and the fullname mem */
            dfree(subdnp);
        }
    }
}
```

The line where the recursive function call takes place is:

```c
                    scan_and_display_dirs_recur(dnd, 0);
```

#### Seeing the recursive function calls as they happen:

You can see this in operation if you run `busybox ls` in a debugger. First install the [debug symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debug_symbol) by [enabling -dbgsym.ddeb packages](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Debug%20Symbol%20Packages#Getting_-dbgsym.ddeb_packages) and then installing the `busybox-static-dbgsym` package. Install `gdb` as well (that's the debugger).

```bash
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gdb busybox-static-dbgsym
```

I suggest debugging `coreutils ls` on a simple directory tree.

If you don't have one handy, make one (this works the same way as the `mkdir -p` command in [WinEunuuchs2Unix's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/875471/22949)):

```bash
mkdir -pv foo/{bar/foobar,baz/quux}
```

And populate it with some files:

```bash
(shopt -s globstar; for d in foo/**; do touch "$d/file$((i++))"; done)
```

You can verify `busybox ls -R foo` works as expected, producing this output:

```
foo:
bar    baz    file0

foo/bar:
file1   foobar

foo/bar/foobar:
file2

foo/baz:
file3  quux

foo/baz/quux:
file4
```

Open `busybox` in the debugger:

```bash
gdb busybox
```

GDB will print some information about itself. Then it should say something like:

```
Reading symbols from busybox...Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug/.build-id/5c/e436575b628a8f54c2a346cc6e758d494c33fe.debug...done.
done.
(gdb)
```

`(gdb)` is your prompt in the debugger. The first thing you'll tell GDB to do on this prompt is to set a breakpoint at the start of the `scan_and_display_dirs_recur()` function:

```
b scan_and_display_dirs_recur
```

When you run that, GDB should tell you something like:

```
Breakpoint 1 at 0x5545b4: file coreutils/ls.c, line 1026.
```

Now tell GDB to run `busybox` with `ls -R foo` (or whatever directory name you want) as its arguments:

```
run ls -R foo
```

You may see something like this:

```
Starting program: /bin/busybox ls -R foo

Breakpoint 1, scan_and_display_dirs_recur (dn=dn@entry=0x7e6c60, first=1) at coreutils/ls.c:1026
1026    coreutils/ls.c: No such file or directory.
```

If you do see `No such file or directory`, as above, that's okay. The purpose of this demonstration is just to see when the `scan_and_display_dirs_recur()` function has been called, so GDB doesn't need to examine the actual source code.

Notice that the debugger hit the breakpoint even before any directory entries were printed. It breaks on the *entrace* to that function, but the code in that function must run for any directories to be enumerated for printing.

To tell GDB to continue, run:

```
c
```

Each time `scan_and_display_dirs_recur()` is called, the breakpoint will be hit again, so you will get to see recursion in action. It looks like this (including the `(gdb)` prompt and your commands):

```
(gdb) c
Continuing.
foo:
bar    baz    file0

Breakpoint 1, scan_and_display_dirs_recur (dn=dn@entry=0x7e6cb0, first=first@entry=0) at coreutils/ls.c:1026
1026    in coreutils/ls.c
(gdb) c
Continuing.

foo/bar:
file1   foobar

Breakpoint 1, scan_and_display_dirs_recur (dn=dn@entry=0x7e6cf0, first=first@entry=0) at coreutils/ls.c:1026
1026    in coreutils/ls.c
(gdb) c
Continuing.

foo/bar/foobar:
file2

foo/baz:
file3  quux

Breakpoint 1, scan_and_display_dirs_recur (dn=dn@entry=0x7e6cf0, first=first@entry=0) at coreutils/ls.c:1026
1026    in coreutils/ls.c
(gdb) c
Continuing.

foo/baz/quux:
file4
[Inferior 1 (process 2321) exited normally]
```

The function has `recur` in its name... does BusyBox only use it when the `-R` flag is given? In the debugger, this is easy to find out:

```
(gdb) run ls foo
Starting program: /bin/busybox ls foo

Breakpoint 1, scan_and_display_dirs_recur (dn=dn@entry=0x7e6c60, first=1) at coreutils/ls.c:1026
1026    in coreutils/ls.c
(gdb) c
Continuing.
bar    baz    file0
[Inferior 1 (process 2327) exited normally]
```

Even without `-R`, this particular implementation of `ls` uses the same function to find out what filesystem entries exist and show them.

When you want to quit the debugger, just tell it:

```
q
```

#### How `scan_and_display_dirs_recur()` knows if it should call itself:

Specifically how does it work differently when the `-R` flag is passed? Examining the [source code](https://bazaar.launchpad.net/~vcs-imports/busybox/trunk/view/head:/coreutils/ls.c) (that may not be the exact version on your Ubuntu system) reveals that it checks its internal data structure `G.all_fmt`, where it stores what options it has been invoked with:

```c
            if (ENABLE_FEATURE_LS_RECURSIVE
             && (G.all_fmt & DISP_RECURSIVE)
```

(If BusyBox has been compiled without support for `-R`, then it will also not attempt to display filesystem entries recursively; that's what the `ENABLE_FEATURE_LS_RECURSIVE` part is about.)

Only when `G.all_fmt & DISP_RECURSIVE` is true does the code that contains the recursive function call get run.

```c
                struct dnode **dnd;
                unsigned dndirs;
                /* recursive - list the sub-dirs */
                dnd = splitdnarray(subdnp, SPLIT_SUBDIR);
                dndirs = count_dirs(subdnp, SPLIT_SUBDIR);
                if (dndirs > 0) {
                    dnsort(dnd, dndirs);
                    scan_and_display_dirs_recur(dnd, 0);
                    /* free the array of dnode pointers to the dirs */
                    free(dnd);
                }
```

Otherwise, the function just runs once (per directory specified on the command line).

Comment: Once again, Eliah comes through with a hyper-comprehensive answer. A well deserved +1.

Comment: Oh, so it's not even tail recursion. This must mean there exist some directory contents, listing which will crash busybox due to stack overflow (although it'd be an extremely deep nesting).

Comment: This is astounding. You basically provided OP with a quick lesson in debugging so that they can understand exactly how the thing is working. Superb.

Answer (score 16):

When you think about it, "recursive" makes sense for commands that act on directories and their files and directories and their files and directories and their files and directories and their files.........

.... until the entire tree from the specified point down has been operated on by the command, in this case listing the contents of any subdirectories of any subdirectories of any subdirectories.......... that exist under the argument(s) of the command

Answer (score 7):

-R is for recursion, which could loosely be called "repeatedly".

Take this code for example:

```
───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
$ mkdir -p temp/a
───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
$ mkdir -p temp/b/1
───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
$ mkdir -p temp/c/1/2
───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
$ ls -R temp
temp:
a  b  c

temp/a:

temp/b:
1

temp/b/1:

temp/c:
1

temp/c/1:
2

temp/c/1/2:
```

The `-p` in making directories allows you to mass create directories with a single command. If one or more of the top-middle directories already exist it's not an error and the middle-lower directories are created.

Then the `ls -R` recursively lists every single directory starting with temp and working it's way down the tree to all the branches.

Now let's look at a complement to the `ls -R` command, ie the `tree` command:

```
$ tree temp
temp
├── a
├── b
│   └── 1
└── c
    └── 1
        └── 2

6 directories, 0 files
```

As you can see `tree` accomplishes the same as `ls -R` except is more concise and dare I say "prettier".

Now let's look at how to recursively remove the directories we just created in one simple command:

```
$ rm -r temp
```

This recursively removes `temp` and all the sub-directories underneath it. ie `temp/a`, `temp/b/1` and `temp/c/1/2` plus the middle directories in between.

Comment: If "ls -R" were to do something *repeatedly* then you'd get the same output multiple times ;) +1 for `tree` though. It's a great tool.

Comment: Yeah poor voice of layman's word. I was trying to find a word in the mainstream making it easier for non programmer types to comprehend. I'll try to think of a better word or delete later.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a simple explanation, it makes sense because when it comes to displaying the content of subdirectories, the same function already knows what to do with a directory. Therefore it just needs to call itself on each subdirectory to get that result!

In pseudocode it looks something like this:

```
recursive_ls(dir)
    print(files and directories)
    foreach (directoriy in dir)
        recursive_ls(directory)
    end foreach
end recursive_ls
```