# Explaining a shell script to recursively print full directory tree

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I found a script to recursively print a full directory tree, but I cannot understand it. Can anyone fully describe it? I have just started shell scripting. Here is the code:

```
#!/bin/bash
walk() {
        local indent="${2:-0}"
        printf "%*s%s\n" $indent '' "$1"
        for entry in "$1"/*; do
                [[ -d "$entry" ]] && walk "$entry" $((indent+4))
        done
}
walk "$1"
```

Comment: `tree -d /path/to/dir` does something very similar btw.

Comment: `printf "%*s%s\n"` should better be either `printf '%*s%s\n'` or `printf "%*s%s\\n"`, see the very helpful `shellcheck` [online](http://www.shellcheck.net) and [for the terminal](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=shellcheck).

Comment: Also of interest: [Why is ls -R called “recursive” listing?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/875370/why-is-ls-r-called-recursive-listing)

Comment: Here is a another script based on this one: https://askubuntu.com/a/968971/566421

Answer (score 9):

This script defines a function `walk()` and then runs `walk` on the first argument passed to the script.

The function first defines a local variable (one known only to the function and its children) `indent`

`indent` is locally defined as `"${2:-0}"`. This means that if `$2` (the second argument received by the `walk` command) is unset, then make it `0`. This variable is `local` so that you cannot pass a second argument to the script yourself.

The function then prints the contents of the directory specified on the command line (`$1`) in this format

```
printf "%*s%s\n" $indent '' "$1"
```

This means, print `$indent` number of spaces, then print the name of the directory as a string (so a number is not expected), then print a newline.

Then the function runs a loop

```
for entry in $1/*; do
```

This assigns every non-hidden file or sub-directory in `$1` (the directory specified as the first argument to `walk`) to the variable `entry` and loops over them, running this command on them:

```
[[ -d "$entry" ]] && walk "$entry" $((indent+4))
```

This means, if `entry` is a directory, then run `walk` on `entry`. Now `walk` has a second argument `$((indent+4))`, which will be used instead of `0` as the new value of `indent`. The effect of this is that the first level directory is not indented at all, but the second level directories are indented 4 spaces, the third level 8 spaces, etc. Since `entry` is now the first argument, `$1` of the `walk` function, it will recurse throughout the structure.

The script ends by running the `walk` function on the positional parameter `$1`, the first argument passed to the script. Usage could be

```
./script directory
```

This means `directory` is `$1`and `walk` will be run on `directory`.

It would be nice if the script printed regular files I think, but they would look confusing without some elaborate formatting. I recommend using `tree` for this purpose instead of the script!