# Recursive bash script to collect information about each file in a directory structure

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

How do I work recursively through a directory tree and execute a specific command on each file, and output the path, filename, extension, filesize and some other specific text to a single file in bash.

Comment: lol, thanks for the edit; i'll be the first to admit i overcomplicate things, because i'm used to being asked 800 irrelevant questions in the hooman world; so i try to answer the obvious ones in the questions; i'll learn though :-)

Comment: OK, I think the question is pretty clear on what should be done, go through directory tree and output info about each file. The question is pretty clear, and judging by amount of answers already, people understand it fairly well. The 3 votes for being unclear are really not deserved to this question

Answer (score 19, accepted):

While `find` solutions are simple and powerful, I decided to create a more complicated solution, that is based on [this interesting function](https://askubuntu.com/questions/962170/explaining-a-shell-script-to-recursively-print-full-directory-tree), which I saw few days ago.

- *More explanations and two other scripts, based on the current are provided [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/969937/566421).*

**1.** Create executable script file, called `walk`, that is located in `/usr/local/bin` to be accessible as shell command:

```
sudo touch /usr/local/bin/walk
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/walk
sudo nano /usr/local/bin/walk
```

- Copy the below script content and use in `nano`: <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd> for paste; <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd> for save; <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> for exit.

**2.** The content of the script `walk` is:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

# Colourise the output
RED='\033[0;31m'        # Red
GRE='\033[0;32m'        # Green
YEL='\033[1;33m'        # Yellow
NCL='\033[0m'           # No Color

file_specification() {
        FILE_NAME="$(basename "${entry}")"
        DIR="$(dirname "${entry}")"
        NAME="${FILE_NAME%.*}"
        EXT="${FILE_NAME##*.}"
        SIZE="$(du -sh "${entry}" | cut -f1)"

        printf "%*s${GRE}%s${NCL}\n"                    $((indent+4)) '' "${entry}"
        printf "%*s\tFile name:\t${YEL}%s${NCL}\n"      $((indent+4)) '' "$FILE_NAME"
        printf "%*s\tDirectory:\t${YEL}%s${NCL}\n"      $((indent+4)) '' "$DIR"
        printf "%*s\tName only:\t${YEL}%s${NCL}\n"      $((indent+4)) '' "$NAME"
        printf "%*s\tExtension:\t${YEL}%s${NCL}\n"      $((indent+4)) '' "$EXT"
        printf "%*s\tFile size:\t${YEL}%s${NCL}\n"      $((indent+4)) '' "$SIZE"
}

walk() {
        local indent="${2:-0}"
        printf "\n%*s${RED}%s${NCL}\n\n" "$indent" '' "$1"
        # If the entry is a file do some operations
        for entry in "$1"/*; do [[ -f "$entry" ]] && file_specification; done
        # If the entry is a directory call walk() == create recursion
        for entry in "$1"/*; do [[ -d "$entry" ]] && walk "$entry" $((indent+4)); done
}

# If the path is empty use the current, otherwise convert relative to absolute; Exec walk()
[[ -z "${1}" ]] && ABS_PATH="${PWD}" || cd "${1}" && ABS_PATH="${PWD}"
walk "${ABS_PATH}"      
echo
```

**3.** Explanation:

- The main mechanism of the `walk()` function is pretty well described by Zanna in her [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/962185/566421). So I will describe only the new part.
- Within the `walk()` function I've added this loop:

  ```bsh
  for entry in "$1"/*; do [[ -f "$entry" ]] && file_specification; done
  ```

  That means for each `$entry` that is a file will be executed the function `file_specification()`.
- The function `file_specification()` has two parts. The first part gets data related to the file - name, path, size, etc. The second part output the data in well formatted form. To format the data is used the command `printf`. And if you want to tweak the script you should read about this command - for example [this article](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/printf).
- The function `file_specification()` is good place where you can put *the specific command that should be execute for each file*. Use this format:

  ```
  command "${entry}"
  ```

  Or you can save the output of the command as variable, and then `printf` this variable, etc.:

  ```
  MY_VAR="$(command "${entry}")"
  printf "%*s\tFile size:\t${YEL}%s${NCL}\n" $((indent+4)) '' "$MY_VAR"
  ```

  Or directly `printf` the output of the command:

  ```
  printf "%*s\tFile size:\t${YEL}%s${NCL}\n" $((indent+4)) '' "$(command "${entry}")"
  ```
- The section to the begging, called `Colourise the output`, initialise few variables that are used within the `printf` command to colourise the output. More about this you could find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5947802/6543935).
- To the bottom of the scrip is added additional condition that deals with absolute and relative paths.

**4.** Examples of usage:

- To run `walk` for the current directory:

  ```bsh
  walk      # You shouldn't use any argument, 
  walk ./   # but you can use also this format
  ```
- To run `walk` for any child directory:

  ```bsh
  walk <directory name>
  walk ./<directory name>
  walk <directory name>/<sub directory>
  ```
- To run `walk` for any other directory:

  ```bsh
  walk /full/path/to/<directory name>
  ```
- To create a text file, based on the `walk` output:

  ```bsh
  walk > output.file
  ```
- To create output file without colour codes ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18000433/6543935)):

  ```bsh
  walk | sed -r "s/\x1B\[([0-9]{1,2}(;[0-9]{1,2})?)?[mGK]//g" > output.file
  ```

**5.** Demonstration of usage:

[image]

Comment: That's whole lot of work, but does look good. Good job !

Comment: What process are you using to make those gifs @pa4080 ?

Comment: @pbhj, under Ubuntu I'm using [Peek](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/08/peek-desktop-gif-screen-recorder-linux) it is simple and nice, but sometimes crashes and doesn't have editing abilities. The most of my GIFs are created under Windows, where I'm recording the the window of the VNC connection. I have a separate desktop machine that mainly I'm using for MS Office and GIF creation :) The tool that I'm using there is [ScreenToGif](http://www.screentogif.com/). It is opensource, free, and has powerful editor and processing mechanisum. Unfortunately I can't find tool like ScreenToGif for Ubuntu.

Answer (score 14):

I'm slightly perplexed as to why nobody has posted it yet, but indeed `bash` does have recursive capabilities, if you enable `globstar` option and use `**` glob. As such, you can write (almost) pure `bash`  script that uses that recursive globstar like this:

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

shopt -s globstar

for i in ./**/*
do
    if [ -f "$i" ];
    then
        printf "Path: %s\n" "${i%/*}" # shortest suffix removal
        printf "Filename: %s\n" "${i##*/}" # longest prefix removal
        printf "Extension: %s\n"  "${i##*.}"
        printf "Filesize: %s\n" "$(du -b "$i" | awk '{print $1}')"
        # some other command can go here
        printf "\n\n"
    fi
done
```

Notice that here we use parameter expansion to get the parts of filename we want and we're not relying on external commands except for getting the file size with `du` and cleaning output with `awk`.

And as it  traverses your directory tree, your output should something like this:

```
Path: ./glibc/glibc-2.23/benchtests
Filename: sprintf-source.c
Extension: c
Filesize: 326
```

Standard rules of script usage apply: make sure it is executable with `chmod +x ./myscript.sh` and run it from current directory via `./myscript.sh` or place it in `~/bin` and run `source ~/.profile`.

Comment: If you're printing the full filename what extra does "extension" give you? Perhaps you really want the MIME information that `"$(file "$i")"` (in the above script as second part of a printf) would return?

Comment: @pbhj To me personally ? Nothing. But OP who asked the question asked for  `output the path, filename, extension, filesize `, so the answer matches what is asked. :)

Answer (score 12):

You can use `find` to do the job

```
find /path/ -type f -exec ls -alh {} \;
```

This will help you if you just want to list all files with size.

`-exec` will allow you to execute custom command or script for each file
`\;` used to parse files one by one, you can use `+;` if you want to concatenate them (means file names).

Comment: This is nice, but not answer to the all the requirements OP mentioned.

Comment: @αғsнιη I just gave him a template to work on. I know, this is not a complete answer to this question, as I think the question itself is broad in scope.

Answer (score 6):

With `find` only.

```
find /path/ -type f -printf "path:%h  fileName:%f  size:%kKB Some Text\n" > to_single_file
```

Or, you could use below instead:

```
find -type f -not -name "to_single_file"  -execdir sh -c '
    printf "%s %s %s %s Some Text\n" "$PWD" "${1#./}" "${1##*.}" $(stat -c %s "$1")
' _ {} \; > to_single_file
```

Comment: Elegant and simple (if you know about `find -printf`). +1

Answer (score 1):

If you know how deep the tree is, the easiest way will be to use the wildcard `*`.

Write up everything you want to do as a shell script or a function

```
function thing() { ... }
```

then run `for i in *; do thing "$i"; done`, `for i in */*; do thing "$i"; done`, ... etc

Within your function/script, you can use some [simple tests](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_01.html) to single out the files you want to work with and do whatever you need to with them.

Comment: "this won't work if any of your filenames have spaces in them" ... because your forgot to quote your variables! Use "$i" instead of `$i`.

Comment: @muru no, the reason it doesn't work is because the "for" loop splits on spaces - "*/*' gets expanded into a space-separated list of all files. You can work around this, e.g. by messing with the IFS, but at that point you might as well just use find.

Comment: @pa4080 not relevant to this answer, but that looks super useful anyway, thanks!

Comment: I think you don't understand how `for i in */*` works. Here, test it: `for i in */*; do printf "|%s|\n" "$i"; done`

Comment: Here is an evidence of quotation marks importance: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oYSj2.png

Comment: @muru You're right; that's very interesting, I wonder how that actually works. I guess it must be interacting with the wildcard somehow to recognize spaces as part of the object, as I know if splits on spaces normally. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

`find` can do this:

```
find ./ -type f -printf 'Size:%s\nPath:%H\nName:%f\n'
```

Have a look at `man find` for other file properties.

If you really need the extension, you can add this:

```
find ./ -type f -printf 'Size:%s\nPath:%H\nName:%f\nExtension:' -exec sh -c 'echo "${0##*.}\n"' {} \;
```