# Find, Duplicate, Rename and Copy to this folder

Tags: command-line, bash, find

First time poster so go easy on me haha.

Beginner linux user, starting out bash scripting and want to make a script to scan my TV Shows folder for fanart.jpg (every show has this file) create a duplicate, rename it (as I understand unix systmes do not auto rename files or allow files with same names in the one directory), and copy to a wallpaper folder.

I've read tons of articles and can not seem to find a relatively simple way of doing this.

So far all Ive got is:

```
cd /mnt/TV\ Shows/

find /mnt/TV\ Shows/ -name fanart.jpg
```

Which gives me a list of all my fanart.jpg files in their respective folders.

Ive tried a few different things after this like `sed` `mv` and `cp` but just cant seem to get it working.

Target folder is `/mnt/Wallpapers/Slideshow/`

Any help would be gratefully appreciated.

Cheers!

Comment: What's the name of your default file browser?

Comment: It may be useful to run it as root to copy the file to the /mnt dir

Comment: You can use find without the CD, then add -exec cp {} , but you need to give each file a unique name. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5607542/why-does-find-exec-mv-target-not-work and https://linuxaria.com/howto/linux-shell-how-to-use-the-exec-option-in-find-with-examples

Comment: How would you want the files to be named in the destination? Possible options I could think of would be to simply give them incrementing numbers, or to give them the name of the directory they were located in, if that one is unique.

Answer (score 2):

Here is example script that users `find`, which output is piped to a `while` loop:

```
find "/mnt/TV Shows/" -type f -name "fanart.jpg" | while IFS= read -r item; do
    NAME="${item##*/}"
    echo cp "$item" "/mnt/Wallpapers/Slideshow/${NAME%.*}-$((i++)).${NAME##*.}"
done
```

- Remove `echo` the do the action.
- The name of the destination file will consist of:

  ```
  ${name of source file}-$((sequential number))-${extension of source file}
  ```
- The numbering will start from `0`, because the variable `$i` has not been pre-initialized. You can put `i=1;` before `find` to start numbering from `1`.

---

Here is more complicated [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) script that uses  the `globstart` option `**` to make recursive search for a file within a folder. If there is a coincidence the file will be be copied to a destination folder. You can choice between different patterns of the destination file name by changing the inner (if-fi) part of the script.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

INPUT_PATH="/mnt/TV Shows"
INPUT_FILE_NAME="fanart.jpg"
OUTPUT_PATH="/mnt/Wallpapers/Slideshow"

shopt -s globstar

for item in "${INPUT_PATH}"/**; do
    # If the item is a file and its name is equal to the INPUT_FILE_NAME
    if [[ -f "$item" && "${item##*/}" == "$INPUT_FILE_NAME" ]]; then
        # Compose OUTPUT_FILE name based on the parent directory name
        INPUT_FILE_FULL_PATH="${item%/*}"
        INPUT_FILE_PARENT_DIR="${INPUT_FILE_FULL_PATH##*/}"
        OUTPUT_FILE_NAME="${INPUT_FILE_NAME%.*}-${INPUT_FILE_PARENT_DIR}.${INPUT_FILE_NAME##*.}"
        # Remove 'echo' to execute the command !!!
        echo cp "${item}" "${OUTPUT_PATH}/${OUTPUT_FILE_NAME}"
    fi
done
```

---

References:

- [While loop only processes the first entry of ssh command](https://askubuntu.com/q/979442/566421)
- [Recursive bash script to collect information about each file in a directory structure](https://askubuntu.com/a/968990/566421)