# How to move files under multi-directories into same directory?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, directory, mv

i have so many files under 300 different directories, file tree like:

```
--s1
 - ----abc
 - ----bcd
--s2
 - ----123
 - ----234
```

... etc.

I want to put them together under the same directory, like:

```
--whole
 - ----abc
 - ----bcd
 - ----123
 - ----234 ...
```

Is there any useful bash script in practical?

I coded this piece of bash script:

```
mkdir wavs

for ((i=1;i<=9;i++)); do
    cd ~/wav/train/S000$i
    mv * ~/wav/train/wavs
    cd .. done

for ((i=10;i<=99;i++)); do
    cd ~/wav/train/S00$i
    mv * ~/wav/train/wavs
    cd .. done

for ((i=100;i<=917;i++)); do
    cd ~/wav/train/S0$i
    mv * ~/wav/train/wavs
    cd .. done

echo "ok"
```

but i got the error which i dont understand:

```
./untar.sh: line 24: cd: /wav/train/S0917: No such file or directory 
cp: target '/wav/train/wavs/' is not a directory ok
```

Comment: Hello, David, I've wrote an answer which uses `find`, that IMO is the easiest way to do this job.  If you need to create a bash script here is provided two variants that solve a similar task: https://askubuntu.com/a/1020671/566421

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the simplest way to do this job is by the command `find` (by default it works recursively):

```
find ~/wav/train/S* -type f -name "*.wav" -exec echo mv {} ~/wav/train/wavs/ \;
```

- `~/wav/train/S*` is the search path and it will match to each sub dir that starts with `S`.
- `-type f` will limit  the search only to the files.
- `-name "*.wav"` will limit the search only to the files that ends with `.wav`. Not mandatory.
- `-exec ... \;` will execute the *mentioned* command once for each search coincidence.
- `{}` is a variable that contains the coincidence item.
- remove `echo` from the command `echo mv {} ~/wav/train/wavs/` to do the action.

Further if you want to delete the directories you can use a command as one of these:

```
find ~/wav/train/S* -type d -name "S*" -exec echo rm -r {} \;
find ~/wav/train/S* -type d -name "S*" -delete
```