# Print size of directory content with tree command, but exclude files from report

Tags: command-line, disk-usage, tree, du

I often use

```
du --max-depth=n -h | sort --human-numeric-sort
```

Now I want to use `tree`, in a similar manner.
I found [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/45828/print-size-of-directory-content-with-tree-command-in-tree-1-5) a partial answer

```
tree -sh --sort=size --du
```

where `--du` makes `tree` reporting the cumulative size for each directory (as `du`).
This reports each file as well.
If I want to report only directories, I should add `-d` to `tree`.
But `-d` seems to do two things:

1. Remove files from the report.
2. Remove the size of files from the cumulative total computed for each dir.

Of course, I want only 1, not 2 (as `du` does).
So

```
tree -sh --sort=size --du -d
```

would always report "small" sizes, without considering file sizes.

**Can `tree` overcome this? Is there any alternative?**

Comment: you can use -I 'pattern' to exclude from the report

Comment: Yeah, but this also changes the dir size of the directory shown by `tree`, `tree` only summarizes what it sees...

Comment: `du --max-depth=n -h | sort --human-numeric-sort` is really what I want. Thank you alot. Most of other tutorials on the internet just talk about `du`, and using it just show vague info like /sda... which is not helpful at all.

Answer (score 2):

This is definetely a shortcoming of `tree`. It only summarize sizes of "what it sees". If you ignore files with `-d` or `-I` or if you limit the depth, `tree` will report a "wrong" dir size.

---

If you don't need to restrict levels, this works fine:

```
tree --du -shaC | sed -n '/\[01;34m/p'
```

Wiht `01;34` being the color value for directories from `LS_COLORS` env variable (`...di=01;34...`).

If you want to restrict levels though, the deepest level will still report wrong dir size with this method.

---

Consider using a more advanced tool such as `ncdu`.

See also [this very similar question at U&L SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/238455/combine-the-best-of-du-and-tree).

Comment: Hi, pLumo. Nice idea. But I think the OP asks for something like this: `tree --du -shaC | sed -r '/\[01;34m/!{s/\[.*\]//}'`.

Comment: I didn't find a way to have `ncdu` output a tree, with attached cumulative spaces, so I can e.g. redirect to file and inspect later on.
I can interactively navigate the tree, but that is now what I was looking for.

Comment: You can use `-o -` to output a json that you can then filter with `jq` or `python ` ... But yes you are right, but there might not be an optimal solution

Comment: @pa4080 - Your solution seems to work reasonably well. Have to check the deatils.
do you know of any way to sort by size? `--sort=size` is giving me strange results. Plus, `sed` filtering seems to even screw that strange output.

Comment: Hi, @sancho.sReinstateMonicaCellio, unfortunately I do not have an idea how to do sort by size in a easy way in this context. Probably this topic cold be interesting for you: [Recursive bash script to collect information about each file in a directory structure](https://askubuntu.com/q/968887/566421)

Comment: @pa4080 - Ok, will check it and get back to you if needed. Thanks for the pointer.