# Replace a word in a directory name and in the filenames in that directory

Tags: command-line, scripts, sed, batch-rename, mv

I have a directory structure like this:

```
Bookname Edition 1
  Bookname Edition 1 type1.pdf
  Bookname Edition 1 type2.pdf
Bookname Edition 2
  Bookname Edition 2 type1.pdf
  Bookname Edition 2 type2.pdf
```

I want to recursively change the name from `Edition` to `Volume` of the directory **and** the filenames in those directories.

I started off with this and that's fine if I'm in the directory:

```bsh
for f in *.pdf; do
    a="$(echo $f | sed s/Edition/Volume/)"
    mv "$f" "$a"
done
```

Then I tried this to change all files under the directories, and that's when I got stuck...

Please can you tell me how to do this or give me a better way of doing this. There are 15000 PDFs in 100 directories.

Comment: How did you get stuck exactly? Based on that `for` loop, I would assume nothing happened, but I want to confirm.

Comment: The script above changed all occurrences of Edition to Volume inside the directory. I want to do this from outside the directory as there are over 100 directories full of PDFs. I also want to change the directory name too from Edition to Volume.

Comment: OK, but how did you get stuck exactly?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If your structure only has two levels, you don't need to use recursion.

Don't parse filenames with `sed`. If you want to use regex and `sed` style syntax to rename files, use `rename`. If you're using Ubuntu 17.10, you need to install it

```bsh
sudo apt install rename
```

Then you can use [pa4080's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/998801/527764).

With `rename`, use the `-n` option for testing.

```bsh
rename -n 'expression' file(s)
```

You could also just use the `mv` command. As a one-line command:

```bsh
for d in ./*/; do mv -v "$d" "${d/Edition/Volume}"; done; for f in ./*/*; do mv -v "$f" "${f/Edition/Volume}"; done
```

You can use `echo` for testing with `mv`, ie `echo mv -v source dest`, but it gives inaccurate results here, unless you test and then run the loops separately.

As a script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

# rename directories first
for d in ./*/; do
    mv -v "$d" "${d/Edition/Volume}"
done

# now rename files
for f in ./*/*; do
    mv -v "$f" "${f/Edition/Volume}"
done
```

`mv` and `rename` recognise `--` to indicate the end of options. Since all paths begin with `./` in this example, we do not need to use that, but if paths may begin with `-`, then use `--` at the end of options, eg `rename -n -- 's/foo/bar/' *`, to prevent those paths being interpreted as options.

Comment: Thanks for this - it changed the directory names but the files underneath havent been renamed.

Comment: @Bishop well, it should. What exactly did you do?

Answer (score 7):

You could use the command `rename` two times to accomplish this task:

```bsh
rename 's/Edition/Volume/' */        # rename the directories
rename 's/Edition/Volume/' */*.pdf   # rename the PDF files inside
```

---

Here are two similar questions:

- [Recursive bash script](https://askubuntu.com/questions/968887/recursive-bash-script)
- [Explaining a shell script to recursively print full directory tree](https://askubuntu.com/q/962170/566421)

Answer (score 7):

On multi- level directories, you can do it in one step, but the issue is that you need to make sure to rename the directories from bottom to top, to prevent the command or script to change the directory name before its content is changed.

In python, you can use:

```
os.walk
```

in combination with

```
topdown=False
```

In a script:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
import shutil
import sys

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(sys.argv[1], topdown=False):
    for f in files:
        shutil.move(
            root+"/"+f, root+"/"+f.replace("Edition", "Volume").strip()
        )
    for dr in dirs:
        shutil.move(
            root+"/"+dr, root+"/"+dr.replace("Edition", "Volume").strip()
        )
```

Save the script as `change_name.py`, run it with the directory as argument:

```
python3 /path/to/change_name.py <directory>
```

This works recursively on any number of levels.

Comment: You could use `os.path.join` instead of concatenating strings with `"/"`.

Comment: @EricDuminil absolutely, but in this situation (script in answer), I used the less verbose option. There is no difference in functionality whatsoever. Thanks though.

Comment: This worked for me, I just added to args to get the find and replace from the input.
`root+"/"+f, root+"/"+f.replace(sys.argv[2], sys.argv[3]).strip()`

Comment: @zanna 's solution worked for me until as you explained **top-down** happened.

Answer (score 2):

Use `find` with the `-depth` option combined with `prename`:

```
find [DIRS...] -depth | prename -n 's|Edition(?=[^/]*$)|Volume|'
```

Explanation:

- `-depth` selects directory children before their parents. A tool “consuming” the selected path names for renaming can then rename children before their parents.
- `s|Edition(?=[^/]*$)|Volume|` replaces the first occurrence of `Edition` in the path name with `Volume` *but only* if the remainder doesn't contain a `/`, i. e. it only applies to the last path name component (achieved by the positive look-ahead `(?=[^/]*$)`).
- `-n` tells `prename` to not actually rename the paths but to print how it would rename them. **Remove this option to actually rename them.**